# In how many ways can a cricket team of 11 members be selected from 15 players with the following conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can a cricket team of 11 members be selected from 15 players,so that a particular player is included and another player is left out.

Options
1)216  2)826  3)286  4) 386

My Approach:

I am not able to think the exact Ans As i know only part of it.

i.e If a particular player is included then it can be solved in 14C10 and If the particular player is not included then it can be  solved in $14$C$11$.

> Can Anyone give me the Hint how to solve the problem?

Comment: So you want to select a rest-of-the-team comprising 10 players among the 13 non-particular players?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since one player has to be included in the team you have to select only 10 more players. Since another player has to be kept out of the team you have only 13 players to select from. So the number of ways is = choosing 10 players out of 13 players $=  \binom{13}{10} = 286$